# How to Change image inside listbox in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

how i can change image inside listbox in windows phone,when user will select a item in list box i want to change image for that particular item i am using following code

```
  <ListBox x:Name="list_contacts" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="list_contacts_SelectionChanged" Foreground="White" Height="540" >

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0">                                       
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContactResults"  Text="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Vardana" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContactRe"  Text="{Binding PhoneNumbers[0], Mode=OneWay}"  FontSize="22" FontFamily="Vardana" Margin="10, 50, 0, 0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Margin="400,30,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Image Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="img_network_status" Source="/Assets/Images/gray.circle.png" Width="40" Height="40" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center"  BorderBrush="Black" >
                                        <Image Visibility="Visible" Source="/Assets/Images/line.png" Height="45" Width="500" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,40,0,0" />
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if use the ObservableCollection class to store a list of images.

Then you can add code in the SelectionChanged event handler for change the image of the selected item.

Comment: Could you please send any example

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the image path to a value in your ViewModel and exchange the path value after the user selected the image:

```
<Image Grid.Column="1"  x:Name="img_network_status" Source="{Binding YourPathToTheImageInYourViewModel}" Width="40" Height="40" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

Another option would be to have a `IsSelected` Property in your ViewModel which reflects that the item is currently selected. You would have to set/unset it manually! This property could then be used in any [Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) to show a different image, change the font color, change the visibility or whatever. Converters are often underestimated as just formating of text but can also be used to convert a boolean to any other property (e.g. [Visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx))